# Laravel trait redirect back with session

Tags: php, laravel

```
//inside of trait method
redirect()->back()->with('success', $response['message'])->send();
```

I have a method inside of trait required redirect back to previous page with flash session, but about code only redirect back without session. (controller call this trait method)

I also tried  `Session::flash();` but its not working too

this method will use many times in my app, therefor I need this inside of my trait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **`return`** & I don't know whether you need to use **`send`** or not so use like

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', $response['message']);
```

> See how **`laravel`** do it
>   https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L158-L160

Comment: if i did return it will back to controller, I want trait method auto redirect for me

Answer (score 0):

Just return it from trait in your controller, don't use send() method if you want to redirect back with session.

**// In your trait**

```
return redirect()->back();
```

**then in your controller,**

```
$response = mytraitFunction();
if ($response is instanceof RedirectResponse)
return $response->with('success', $response['message']);
```

Don't forget to use:
**use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;**